# Echo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

When I try to echo JavaScipt code with normal text like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("errorbox").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid invite link!";</script>';
```

It works fine, but when I try to echo something that uses an user input:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("errorbox").innerHTML = "Your New Link: <a href="' . $link . '">' . $link . '</a> (websi.te/' . $link . ')";</script>';
```

It doesn't work, and I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
```

Comment: You need to add escape characters to single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes didn't match. I checked your code in PhpStorm, and after replacing and escaping two quotes in the JavaScript string it din't show a syntax error anymore.

I changed

```
"Your New Link: <a href="' . $link . '">' . $link . '</a> (websi.te/' . $link . ')"
```

to

```
\'Your New Link: <a href="' . $link . '">' . $link . '</a> (websi.te/' . $link . ')\'
```

complete string:

```
echo 
    '<script type="text/javascript">' . 
        'document.getElementById("errorbox").innerHTML = \'Your New Link: <a href="' . $link . '">' . $link . '</a> (websi.te/' . $link . ')\';' . 
    '</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the double quote is wrong.
Try to this. I edited `<a href=\"`...

Good luck.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("errorbox").innerHTML = "Your New Link: <a href=\"' . $link . '\">' . $link . '</a> (websi.te/' . $link . ')";</script>';
```